# Can't start Homebrew PostgreSQL install on Mac OS X - "Permission Denied"

Tags: database, macos, postgresql

I have a Postgresql installed via Homebrew and after a crash I can not start server anymore..

if I do

```
 $ pg_ctl start
```

I get

```
pg_ctl: no database directory specified and environment variable PGDATA unset
```

If I do

```
$ pg_ctl -D /Library/PostgreSQL/data start
```

I get

```
pg_ctl: could not open PID file "/Library/PostgreSQL/data/postmaster.pid": Permission denied
```

Everything was working just fine and then.. out of the blue, this.

The data folder above has permissions set at "Everything" for postgres user and "None" for everyone..

Path looks fine  (in my ~/.bash_profile)

```
export PATH=/usr/local/bin:$PATH
```

Comment: Surprised this was closed, rather than moved to apple.stackexchange.com or dba.stackexchange.com.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When you first started Pg, did you let homebrew start it for you, or did you manually start it with `pg_ctl` ? I ask because I'm guessing you probably need to start and stop Pg using homebrew scripts and/or using `launchd` rather than directly via `pg_ctl`. I don't use homebrew (or Mac OS X much) but a quick search suggests that homebrew installs of Pg are usually started and stopped via `launchd` and `~/Library/LaunchAgents/org.postgresql.postgres.plist` .

If you want to manage it manually:

What user does homebrew usually run PostgreSQL as? If you're launching Pg via `pg_ctl` you need to run it as the right user. From vague memory of other discussion I've seen about homebrew here, it's probably a user named `postgres` or `postgres_` . Double-check using:

```
ls -ld /Library/PostgreSQL/data
```

and see what the owning user is, then run:

```
sudo -u postgres_ pg_ctl -D /Library/PostgreSQL/data start
```

... replacing "postgres_" with the owner of the datadir.

I suspect the reason you're getting permissions errors is that you probably didn't recursively apply the changes. Please don't; run Pg as the correct user instead.